# Criar .exe ou .bat para abrir arquivo como outro usuário

Tags: windows, batch, configuração, .exe

Como faço para criar um arquivo para executar um `.exe` com outro usuário, com valores de usuário e senha setados.
Ex: `user:max.rogerio` e `password: 123456`

Tentei utilizar o `run as` mas toda vez que inicia o `windows` ele pede a senha novamente.
Gostaria que ele não pedisse mais a senha pois ja estaria setado juntamente com o meu usuario.

Comment: Quais opções você passa para o comando "runas"?

Comment: @MurilloGoulart passei `user` e `savecred`, mas ai ele pede a senha toda vez q inicio o computador